# Fluentd does not flush any data to elastic search - but does flush upon shutdown

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd

I have a fluentd + elastic search + kibana setup. Fluentd is configured to output to elastic search with this plugin:
https://github.com/uken/fluent-plugin-elasticsearch . The problem is that fluentd will never flush its buffers to elastic search whilst it is running, it just stores the data in the memory buffer. Upon issuing a shutdown the buffer is flushed and elastic search is updated.

This issue occurs despite setting `flush_interval 60s`  and `buffer_chunk_limit 25k` . Default values also give the same problem.

Fluentd collector log file output and cfg:

```
    2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/supervisor.rb:202:supervise: starting fluentd-0.10.48
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/supervisor.rb:304:read_config: reading config file path="/etc/fluent/fluent.conf"
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered buffer plugin 'file'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered buffer plugin 'memory'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'debug_agent'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'exec'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'forward'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'gc_stat'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'http'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'monitor_agent'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'object_space'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'status'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'tcp'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'unix'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'syslog'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered input plugin 'tail'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'copy'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'exec'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'exec_filter'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'file'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'forward'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'null'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'roundrobin'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'stdout'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'tcp'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'unix'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'test'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:87:block in configure: gem 'fluent-plugin-elasticsearch' version '0.3.0'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:87:block in configure: gem 'fluentd' version '0.10.48'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:91:configure: using configuration file: <ROOT>
  <source>
    type forward
    port 24224
    bind 0.0.0.0
  </source>
  <source>
    type syslog
    port 5544
    protocol_type tcp
    bind 0.0.0.0
    tag index.syslog
  </source>
  <match index.**>
    type elasticsearch
    logstash_format true
    host localhost
    port 9200
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key tag
  </match>
</ROOT>
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:101:block in configure: adding source type="forward"
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:101:block in configure: adding source type="syslog"
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: fluent/engine.rb:117:block in configure: adding match pattern="index.**" type="elasticsearch"
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [trace]: fluent/plugin.rb:72:register_impl: registered output plugin 'elasticsearch'
2014-07-11 11:45:44 +0100 [info]: plugin/in_forward.rb:75:listen: listening fluent socket on 0.0.0.0:24224
2014-07-11 11:45:45 +0100 [debug]: plugin/in_syslog.rb:183:listen: listening syslog socket on 0.0.0.0:5544 with tcp
2014-07-11 11:45:45 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:189:initialize: accepted fluent socket from '10.18.80.20:57119': object_id=70254255494700
2014-07-11 11:45:45 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:245:on_close: closed fluent socket object_id=70254255494700
2014-07-11 11:45:46 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:189:initialize: accepted fluent socket from '10.18.80.20:57120': object_id=70254256323480
2014-07-11 11:45:46 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:245:on_close: closed fluent socket object_id=70254256323480
2014-07-11 11:45:47 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:189:initialize: accepted fluent socket from '10.18.80.20:57121': object_id=70254256319280
2014-07-11 11:45:47 +0100 [trace]: plugin/in_forward.rb:245:on_close: closed fluent socket object_id=70254256319280
.......
```

Could anyone help explain why fluentd is not flushing to elastic search? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much troubleshooting I found that there was a bug in the specific version of ruby installed that caused a thread to deadlock when starting up. The issue did not appear when shutting down as it was being called a differently. This is a specific bug re ruby 2.0.0-p353 ; the next release ruby 2.0.0-p451 fixes the issue.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/fluentd/t2uKfttiYCw/P8zy5kZpEIIJ

Answer (score 1):

Are there fluentd buffers under /var/spool/fluentd? Do they grow?

Could you check ElasticSearch log?

```
grep --color FrameException /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log
org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.TooLongFrameException: HTTP content length exceeded 655360000 bytes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your pasted stdout, it does not look like "flush_interval" is set for out_elasticsearch plugin:

```
<match index.**>
  type elasticsearch
  logstash_format true
  host localhost
  port 9200
  include_tag_key true
  tag_key tag
</match>
```

Can you try inserting a line "flush_interval 60s" into the above config, wait for a minute or so, and see if data is showing up in Elasticsearch?

Comment: Thanks for your help but that has had no effect. I left the line out to convey that the default value was being used.

Comment: I see. THanks for the clarification. Do you think you can run Fluentd with the `-vv` verbose option and share the log output? That might help resolve the issue

Comment: That is what I have already added above. [trace] is added with -vv

Comment: Do you have anything beyond the last list you pasted? The logs shown are up to starting up Fluentd and accepting a couple of messages via in_forward.

Comment: There is no more useful information in the log, just a repeat of the trace log lines from in_forward.

Comment: A pathological possibility: Elasticsearch is having an issue. Can you use out_copy and copy results to stdout like this:
<match index.**>
  type copy
  <store>
    type stdout
  </store>
  <store>
    type elasticsearch
    logstash_format true
    host localhost
    port 9200
    include_tag_key true
    tag_key tag
  </store>
</match>